# MuleSoft's rollback database transaction problem

Tags: transactions, mulesoft

In mulesoft I try to insert payload into tables inside try block, database and try block are configured with transaction already. I am using on Error continue instead of on error propagate.
But it seems it will not rollback database transaction when error happend.
My question is do I have to have to use on error propagate for rollback database transaction?
could I use on error continue to archeive that?

Any hints will be more than welcome!

```
<error-handler >
            <on-error-continue enableNotifications="false" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="82981086-6eb6-4264-8121-d9887385788e" type="ANY">
                <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="d3fd89de-ddcf-4991-9c20-5e5132bbb1cd" >
                    <ee:message >
                    </ee:message>
                    <ee:variables >
                        <ee:set-variable variableName="insertDatabaseFailed" ><![CDATA["true"]]></ee:set-variable>
                    </ee:variables>
                </ee:transform>
            </on-error-continue>
        </error-handler>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the "On Error Continue" error handler in MuleSoft does not facilitate transaction rollback. This error handler is designed to let the flow continue processing despite encountering errors, without any transaction rollback mechanism.

If you require transaction rollback upon encountering an error, you should employ the "On Error Propagate" error handler. This handler ensures that the transaction is rolled back before the flow processing continues.

Also regarding your follow-up question:

> Could I just manually rollback a transaction in MuleSoft's "On Error
> Continue" block?

There doesn't seem to be a way to do a manual transaction rollback within the "On Error Continue" block.

For a comprehensive understanding of XA transactions in MuleSoft, refer to the documentation on [XA Transactions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/xa-transactions).

There are also a couple of examples provided ( with flow code ) on [Using XA Transactions with Different Resources](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/xa-transactions#using-xa-transactions-with-different-resources) that demonstrate how XA transactions behave in scenarios involving "On Error Continue" and "On Error Propagate" error handlers, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Using on error continue means that you are handling the error so it will not trigger the rollback. See what the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/transaction-management#error-handling) says on error handling in transactions:

> - On Error Propagate
>
>   - If the on-error-propagate error handler is inside the error-handler scope corresponding to the component that began the
>     transaction:
>
>     The transaction is rolled back before executing the processors of the on-error-propagate scope. This means that the processors inside
>     the error handler do not run within the transaction.
>   - If the on-error-propagate error handler is inside an element that did not start the transaction:
>
>     The transaction is not rolled back and the processors inside the on-error-propagate error handler run within the transaction.
>     Remember that some scopes and routers behave differently when
>     executing within a transaction.
> - On Error Continue
>
>   The error is handled, the transaction remains active and is able to commit. The processors inside the on-error-continue run within the
>   transaction.

Comment: thanks for the deatiled reply, Could I just mannully rollback transaction in MuleSoft's on Error Continue block? something like in java catch Exception , rollback transaction ,but does not re throw new Exception?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. What are you trying to achieve that on error continue doesn't work for you? Maybe you want to ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the DB inside a TRY block, select "ALWAYS JOIN" in the database transaction type config, and in the TRY block, select "ALWAYS BEGIN" for transactional action.

check this article::
https://mulesy.com/transaction-management-using-try/